# How do I apply CSS style to ASCII character

Tags: html, css

I'd like to reduce the weight of a my ascii degree character `&deg;` in my html document.  Does anybody know how?

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <div style="position:absolute; top: 70; right: 0;">
                    72
                    <span>&deg;</span>
                    F
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div{
font-size: 80px;
margin: 2px;
padding: 2px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: aFont;
    src: url(ostrich-rounded-webfont.ttf);
}

.fontclass{
    font-family: aFont, Helvetica;
    color: #FFFFFF;
 }

a:link {
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
}

div span{
    font-weight:1;
    font-size:1px;
}
```

Comment: within a particular element or within the whole document

Comment: only the ascii element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/44wzgk0v/)**

CSS:

```
p {
    font-weight:bold;
}
p span {
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:11px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>Test test Test test Test test  <span> &deg;</span> Test test Test test Test test Test test </p>
```

Edit: **[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/44wzgk0v/3/)**

CSS:

```
p, div{
    font-weight:bold;
}
p span, div span {
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:11px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div stile="position:absolute; top:70; right:0;"> 89 <span> &deg;</span> </div>
```

Comment: I can't make it work with the span inside of a <div> tag, any ideas for that?

Comment: Can you post ur code both html and css what you are using.. so that i can make a try?

Comment: `<div stile="position:absolute; top:70; right:0;">
72 <span> &deg; </span> F
</div `

Comment: Its working fine with the html code you posted. you can check my edit